# After a recent update to Notepad++ 7.6.6, I cannot enter accented characters such as á, é, ó, ê, etc

Tags: notepad++

I've been using Notepad++ for several years now.

Recently I updated to Notepad++ 7.6.6 (this time I think I did a full reinstall instead of actually updating when prompted).

After updating I noticed that when I try to enter accented characters such as á, é, í, ó, ú, â, ê, ô, etc by for example typing `´ + a` (expecting á), Notepad++ ends up printing ´´a, ´´e, ´´i, ´´o, ´´u, ^^a, ^^e, etc. That is, Notepad++ duplicates the accent and enters the accents before the accented character.

I have Win10 and a Portuguese keyboard, so I first type the accent `´` then I type the character, for example `a`, expecting the result is `á` but Notepad gives me `´´a` instead. This all worked fine for years in Notepad++, only after updating to v.7.6.6 it started to not print the accented characters. But like I mentioned, this time I think I updated by doing a full reinstall because I lost a lot of configuration (shortcuts, etc) and had to reinstall the plugins, although I don't use many of them.

Document is encoded in UTF-8 as always. I tested on MS Word and Wordpad and accents are printing as expected.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add that useful info to the original question so all may see it. Please don't click [Add Comment] to reply; comments can get pushed down the screen and hidden under a link. We want everyone to see the details they need to help you.

Comment: I use the US-International keyboard layout, and I have N++ 7.6.6 on my Windows 10 workstation. I cannot reproduce this; if I type `'` + `a`, I get `á`, as expected.

Comment: This question isn’t a candidate to be deleted.  Vandalizing your own question isn’t something you should do.